# Move focus to checkbox after _onleave event

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have a textbox with an _onleave event.
I verify the text in the textbox and generate a messagebox.
In most cases focus moves, to whatever was clicked, once the messagebox clears, but not when it was a checkbox.
Is there any way I can capture what was clicked that generated the _onleave event so that I can assign focus  to it ( or in this case click the checkbox) once _onleave code is completed.
I have tried:

```
Control control = (Control)sender;
control.Select();
```

Unfortunately, this captures the initial textbox and returns focus to it.
Thanks

To demonstrate with an example
Start a new Windows Form Application. Place on it two textboxes and a checkbox. Use the following code to run the application. The problem is explained above and demonstrated in this sample.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Size=new Size(223,22);
            textBox1.Text = "Click here first - has leave event";
            textBox2.Size = new Size(111, 22);
            textBox2.Text = "Click here second";
            checkBox1.Text = "Try clicking checkbox";
        }

        private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("If you clicked the textbox, focus should move to it" + Environment.NewLine + "If you clicked the checkbox, checkstate will not change or will it gain focus");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to be more specific. The question _”Is there any way I can capture what was clicked that generated the _onleave event so that I can assign focus to it”_... this is somewhat confusing in a sense that EACH control has its own `Leave` event. You may want to peruse… [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am not sure what is confusing about the question as I think I have asked the question fairly succinctly with an example. Clearly EACH control has its own leave event but you need to click another control to execute it. Whichever control you click will get focus in my example except a checkbox, which does not become clicked/unclicked after the leave event.

Comment: If you feel you have… _”asked the question fairly succinctly with an example”_... then you definitely need to read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Further detail added

Comment: @JohnG I have added more detail. Do you have an answer?

Comment: I am still not sure what the text box has to do with the check box. If you remove the `MessageBox` statement from the `textBox1_Leave` event this “focus” problem does not occur. I will not argue, that when the second text box is clicked when the first text box has focus…you can “SEE” the focus has changed, however when the check box has focus, you cannot really “See” this focus. If you add an event for `checkBox1.Enter` and put a message box in that event you will see the check box has focus but there is no visual indication of this on the check box control.

Comment: I am obviously missing something from what you are ultimately trying to achieve.

Comment: @JohnG  You have solved the problem for me and if you post your reply I will mark it as answered. The situation is a little more complex, in as much as the messagebox gives the user the option to add the textbox contents to a database for future use. I wanted this to happen wherever they happened to move to, and click on the form, including a checkbox. You were correct to suggest that the checkbox still got focus which I didn't realise. I used your suggestion and used an enter event on the checkbox to change its checkstate.. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am not sure what to post as an answer. I am glad you got it working, and since it appears I was the only user to respond, I would say, “go ahead and delete the question”. I doubt if the question will be much help for others and that way you will not have an open question. I will admit that you DID improve your question and your edit did make it clear what you were having problems with. If you want, I will post my last comment if you want to have the question answered. Otherwise, I do not have a problem with you deleting the question… your call.

Comment: @JohnG Thanks again. Not sure of correct procedure here but by the sounds of it deleting the question may be the best option. I will do that in the next couple of days.